# Syntax error: when using "check program" in monit

Tags: monit

I have the following configuration in Monit:

```sh
check program raid-md127 with path "/sbin/mdadm --misc --test /dev/md127"
    if status != 0 then alert
```

When restart monit, I get the following error:

```sh
root@NAS2:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# /etc/init.d/monit restart
Stopping daemon monitor: monit.
Starting daemon monitor: Syntax error:
/etc/monit/monitrc:29: Error: syntax error 'raid-md127'
```

Can you advice, please?

Comment: The syntax seems correct. What is the monit version ? Could it be an error from a previous line ? Did you tried without the dash ? I have checks with dash running fine on my side

Comment: `root@NAS2:/home/murugan# monit -V
This is Monit version 5.4
Copyright (C) 2001-2012 Tildeslash Ltd. All Rights Reserved.`

Comment: `root@NAS2:/home/murugan# /etc/init.d/monit restart
Stopping daemon monitor: monit.
Starting daemon monitor: monit/etc/monit/monitrc:323: Warning: Program does not exist: '"/sbin/mdadm misc test /dev/md127"'
.
Warning: Please, set start delay for monit in config file
         and delete /etc/monit/monit_delay file.
root@NAS2:/home/murugan#`

Comment: Monit 5.4, this is very old. Could you consider upgrading to a newer version ? Maybe this is a bug. However, warning error at restart is different: it complained about not being able to run the program and all the dash seem to have disappeared (if not removed by serverfault). So it is probably a bug at monit level.

Answer (score 3):

The functionality to use parameters in the command was first introduced in Monit 5.7;
https://mmonit.com/monit/changes/

You need to upgrade to a newer version of Monit.